# Make correct iteration for parallel threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

i got some troubles at using parallel threads. I made each Student Class a thread, so each Student need to ask for a Team. The problem is that it need to be limited to 20 request at the same time. So i made this in a StudentHandler:

```
int MAX = 20;
int ACTUAL = 0;
public boolean thereIsRoom(){
   return ACTUAL < MAX;
}
public void requestTeam(Student student){
   if(thereIsRoom()){
        ACTUAL += 1;
        System.out.println(ACTUAL);
        for(int x=0; x<teams.size(); x++){
            // student does stuff
        }
        ACTUAL -= 1;
        System.out.println(ACTUAL);
   }
}
```

The output gets something like this:

```
1
stuff
0
1
2
3
4
stuff
.
.
31
```

An so on, but i don't understand why there are more than my limit when it prints ACTUAL. How can fix it? It would be necessary make StudentHandler another thread? if it is then how?

Comment: *"How can fix it?"* Make the code thread-safe. Since that's a big topic, with many potential solutions, you need to start **researching** (aka study) the topic of *thread safety* in Java, aka *concurrent programming* in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure why you are getting this behavior, but there is one glaring hole in your thread safety and fixing this might solve the problem. The issue is that there is a time gap in between when the `thereIsRoom` test is done and when the variable `AVAILABLE` is updated. This allows a classic issue that is so well known it's been given its own name: *race condition*.

For example, if 10 student threads all attempt to join the class at virtually the same time and the processor sequences the tests prior to running the code after the if test, they could all get in even though the limit will be exceeded once all the AVAILABLE increments get processed.

To fix this, the test and the increment must be crafted as an *atomic* operation. The most usual course is to use [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html). Sometimes there are alternatives to synchronization. For example, instead of having the thread directly try to enter the class, create a queue that handles the entrance requests that prevents the race condition from occurring.

A search on "race condition" should bring up many articles covering various strategies for handling the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i did have no knowing about the "race condition" term, so after a reading i solved the problem using `synchronized` in the `thereIsRoom` method and turning `int ACTUAL` to `volatile int ACTUAL`